# Powershell and dbo.sysjobsteps.Command field being truncated - not a length issue

Tags: sql-server, powershell

On the accepted answer to [Export SQL Agent jobs with steps and scripts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/90852/1192), there is a comment:

> Command is unlikely to get pulled into Excel very nicely. – [Aaron Bertrand ♦](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) Feb 2 '15 at 21:27

This seems very true.

I am trying to pull the `dbo.sysjobsteps.Command` field into a csv file using Powershell Export-Csv.  The data seems to be truncated as of the first space found in the Command field (has nothing to do with a length limitation).

Do you know why?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. It's a bit hard to tell what's actually happening without more information. Could you share the input, the actual powershell script and the truncated output?

Comment: How are you checking the .csv file - by opening in Excel, or in a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

Using the script [Powershell export query to csv](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/03/powershell-export-query-to-csv.html), I was able to run it under Powershell and successfully export the job commands without encountering any truncation.  Are you doing something different?  Here is the script I ran:

```
$server = "."
$database = "msdb"
$query = "SELECT 
    j.Name 
    , j.[Description] 
    , js.Step_ID 
    , js.Step_Name
    , js.Database_Name 
    , js.Command 
    --, j.*, js.* 
FROM dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN dbo.sysjobsteps js
    ON js.job_id = j.job_id 
--WHERE j.enabled = 1
ORDER BY j.name, js.Step_ID"

$extractFile = "C:\Scripts\TestCsv.csv"

$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.Connection = $connection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile
```

Comment: Just a note, but you can use the built-in format operator, `-f`, instead of `String.Format()`.  Like so:  `$connectionString = $connectionTemplate -f $server, $database`.  I'd also tend to use `$command = $connection.CreateCommand()` to instance the command and assign the connection in one line.